# Why EPROCESS and KPROCESS which are part of kernel are accessible from userland?

Tags: windows, process, kernel

the eprocess and kprocess (which is part of eprocess) are part of kernel and resides in the kernel memory. But how I can access their content in WinDBG (using dt command). I think they are meant to be segragated and not-accessible from the user-land (WinDBG run in userland?). I'm a bit confused and any detailed and evidence-backed answer is much appreciated.

Comment: The system can make any operation available via system calls, of course gated by checking for privileges such as SeDebugPrivilege. Prior to Vista, kernel debugger commands were available via `NtSystemDebugControl`. That's locked down now, for the most part. Currently for local kernel debugging, kd.exe and windbg.exe have an embedded driver named kldbgdrv.sys that gets extracted to System32, loaded, and opened as "\\?\kldbgdrv". This driver uses the kernel routine `KdSystemDebugControl`. Kernel debugger commands are sent to it via `DeviceIoControl`.

Comment: Lots of thanks buddy for your clear expalanation, so this means the kernel space is still non-accessible by user (possibly that's why OllyDBG cannot show it) and only special debuggers like (WinDBG can do it)? why it is not possible for an executable to use the same approach (as kd / windbg) to access it's own kernel space?

Comment: Search around. I'm sure someone has reverse-engineered the IOCTL API of the kldbgdrv.sys driver. The debugger commands for `KdSystemDebugControl` are well known. However, this still depends on the system being booted with local kernel debugging enabled and still depends on admin access to get SeDebugPrivilege. It's not a facility that an application could generally rely on. It's meant for developers and system administrators to investigate and resolve problems.